# Ensure that communication between iOS application and back-end succeeded

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, keychain

**Simple question:** How to ensure that a communication between an iOS application and a back-end succeeded?

---

**Detail:** For most of the API call in our mobile application, it can be "OK" if the communication between the application and the server fails (for network reason or other), we can just display a message to the user with a retry button to reload his news or posts feed for instance.

However, on some occasion, we want to be really confident that the communication between the application and the backend will never fail and the data of this communication will potentially be "lost".

For this, let's take as an example, the In-App Purchases (IAP):

- In my app, an IAP information looks like this:

```swift
struct InAppPurchase{
   // The id of the purchase
   let transactionId: String 
   // The id of the user who purchased
   let userId: String 
   // The IAP product involved in the purchase (10 or 30 in-app coins for example)
   let productId: String 
}
```

- Everytime a user makes a purchase, I want to send this information to the back-end in order to save a history of the purchases made in my application.
- I don't want to miss any of those communications between the application and the server (if a user send me a feedback saying that he paid for some item in my app I want to make sure by checking the history that he really made the purchase)
- If the purchase succeeds but the call to send the information to the server fail (Network error or else), this information can't be lost and must be sent as soon as possible.

I was thinking of this approach:

- Creating a pending purchase array with `UserDefault` or `Keychain` like so

```swift
var pendingPurchases = [InAppPurchase]()
```

- When the user purchases an item, this item is store in the `pendingPurchases` array.
- The application communicates with the back-end by sending this array of IAP
- If I receive the answer code `200 SUCCESS` from the back-end, I can purge the `pendingPurchases` array.
- If I receive another code for an ERROR, I try to send this call another time (limited to 3 in a row, if it is because of bad network, it maybe not needed to try sending the request indefinitely at the moment) until receiving `200 SUCCESS`
- Each time the application is open or switch from background to foreground, I check if the `pendingPurchases` is empty or not. If not empty, I send the request to the server.

---

What do you think of this approach? How do you manage this kind of data that you don't want to be "lost"?

Comment: How does "communication between the application and the backend will never fail" match with "limited to 3 in a row?" If it fails more than 3 times, are you willing to violate your "never fail" rule? Keep in mind that your approach may lead to sending the same message multiple times, so you need to deal with any errors that may be generated due to "already processed."

Comment: By my more than 3 times, I mean if it's failed more than 3 times, maybe it's not the right moment to try indefinitely. Maybe better to keep the data in the UserDefault/Keychain and wait for a better moment to do it. Sorry if it is it confused

Comment: The IAP process basically takes care of this for you; you shouldn't complete the transaction on the payment queue until you have received a success from your server.  Transactions that aren't complete will be re-presented to your transaction observer when your app restarts or when the user taps your "restore" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is wait to "finish the transaction" until you've received a `200` response from your server. If you don't finish the transaction, Apple will save it in a payment queue and keep sending it to you every time the app launches. This will give you an opportunity to handle any retries to your server if needed.

> Finishing a transaction tells StoreKit that you’ve completed
>   everything needed for the purchase. Unfinished transactions remain in
>   the queue until they’re finished, and the transaction queue observer
>   is called every time your app is launched so your app can finish the
>   transactions. Your app needs to finish every transaction, regardless
>   of whether the transaction succeeded or failed.
>
> Complete all of the following actions before you finish the
>   transaction:
>
> - Persist the purchase.
> - Download associated content.
> - Update your app’s UI to let the user access the product.

To finish a transaction, call the finishTransaction: method on the payment queue.

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# The current payment #>;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

You can read more about finishing transactions in Apple's doc below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html